# Postgres installation on MacOSX - problem with psql

Tags: postgresql, installation, psql

I'm currently trying to install Postgres (using the installation package from http://postgresapp.com), i.e. downloading, unpacking, dragging the app into the Applications folder, launching the app. So far, so good.

However, when I then try to use the `psql` command I receive `-bash: psql: command not found`. I tried to follow the solutions in similar questions, but trying to locate the binaries through `which psql` or `locate psql` and so on all didn't work.

Am I doing something wrong? Could someone please provide guidance on how to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how it works on OS X, but on linux, one has to run `updatedb` before trying to find something new with `locate`.

Comment: `mdfind` is the OS X equivalent of `locate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres.app has a short documentation here:

http://postgresapp.com/documentation/

which tells among other things:

> Configure your $PATH
>
> Postgres.app includes many command line tools. If you want to use
> them, you must configure the $PATH variable.
>
> If you are using bash (default shell on OS X), add the following line
> to ~/.bash_profile:
>
> export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin
>
> ...

Not doing that results in the error message you're getting.